# get values from table with foreign key

Tags: php, model, yii2, relation

Hi I have 2 tables and models for them. First of them is

> User

and second

> News

I want to take user id from table `News` and draw her name and surname. There is printscreen of table `News`:

[image]

I am trying to use the function:

```
public function getUrUser()
{
    $q= News::find()->where(['urUser_Id' =>'Id'])->one();
    $RoyalUserData=User::findOne($q);
    //$RoyalUserData= User::find()->where(['Id' => $q])->one();
    return $RoyalUserData->Name;
}
```

But this doesnt work. Only when I prescribe to `q` value 3 for egzample then it work. I know that is the wrong code in my first line of my function probably. I know that is easy but I am a beginner and I've fought with the code for about 1 hour. Can anyone help me?

In my view I use this:

```
<?=$model->getUrUser();?>
```

And I use this in ListView.

My controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model = new NewsForm();
        $searchModel = new NewsSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $dataProvider->setSort(['defaultOrder' => ['Id'=>SORT_DESC]]);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            $model->saveNews();
            return $this->redirect(['/content/news']);
        } else {
            return $this->render('index', [
                        'model' => $model,
                        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

My index where i use _item:

```
echo ListView::widget( [
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_item',
],  $options = ['class' => 'sorter'] ); ?>
```

And content of _item

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
?>  


Treść Newsa:
<?=$model->Text;?> <br>
Autor:
<?=Yii::$app->user->identity->Name?> 
<?=Yii::$app->user->identity->Surname?> <br>
Status Newsa:
<?=$model->cnNewsContentType_Id;?> <br>

  <?= Html::a('Update', ['update', 'id' => $model->Id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?= Html::a('Delete', ['delete', 'id' => $model->Id], [
            'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
            'data' => [
                'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?',
                'method' => 'post',
            ],
        ]) ?><br><br><br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  `News::find()->where(['urUser_Id' =>'Id'])->one()` return a model not a field

then you must get the id field by the model this way

```
public function getUrUser($id)
{
    // you already have the news model so don't need retrieve it 
    //  it's enough pass the urUser_Id by $id

    $RoyalUserData=User::findOne($id);

    return $RoyalUserData->Name;
}
```

Then if you want show the ($RoyalUserData) Name in _item

```
<?=$model->getUrUser($model->urUser_Id);?>
```

Comment: i have error:Trying to get property of non-object in second line of Your code($q) i have the same error in my code

Comment: i editet my forst post look at last code i use in my view maybe it wrong?

Comment: I see now you have where(['urUser_Id' = 'Id'])   this  don't get any result   for find the model you need a value like $ Id  .. i have update the answer ..

Comment: still Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @informer show the controller code of the action related to the view where you want the name ..

Comment: @Informer  in your actionIndex if you render the index view you pass an empty model .. if you redirect to content/news you don't pass the id for the news .. ... where you want show the name ? index View or content/news?

Comment: and i can show there Text and price so i dont know why this doesnt work

Comment: Show the views  related :  _item and the view where you call _item

Comment: this items is a lot from database and i future will be more so i want display all of this items

Comment: And in controller i use new NewsForm extend model and in item it use probably new News extend active records

Comment: If  I understand right in your model you have already usUser_Id the you can use  ite for retrive the RoyalUserData Name ... i have update the answer.

Comment: now i have error in item:Object of class yii\db\ActiveQuery could not be converted to string

Comment: Where exactly .. update the question e show you actul _item code .. and show me the exact error. ..

Comment: now i have error in item:Object of class yii\db\ActiveQuery could not be converted to string where i try to display : <?=$model->getUrUser($model->urUser_Id);?>

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getUrUser()
{
    $q = News::find()->where(['urUser_Id' =>'Id'])->one();
    return $q->user->name;
}
```

In user model you should create [relation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data):

```
class News extends ActiveRecord
{
    // ...

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: and this is in model News and i have relation this relation: `public function getUrUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UrUser::className(), ['Id' => 'urUser_Id']);
    }`

Comment: @Informer try `$q->urUser->name`.